# Unable to use noty in angular

Tags: angular, noty

I have created a notification service using Noty, But It doesnt animate or show properly. Where am I missing?? Do I need to add any script for it?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
declare let require;
const lodash = require('lodash');
const Noty = require('noty');

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NotificationServiceService {

  constructor() { }

  showNotification(text){
    new Noty(lodash.assign({
      text:text,
      type: 'success',
      layout: 'topRight',
      killer:true,
      timeout: 3000,
    })).show();
  }
}
```

This is the code of the service.

Comment: Did you add `noty.css`  to [your build](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles)?

Comment: No. How to do that can u please guide?

Comment: The above link, or for newer versions of Angular: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config, specifically https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#project-asset-configuration

Comment: Lots of thanks buddy. :)

Comment: I suggest that when you find the specific thing you have to add, and which file you have to add it to, you come back here and post it as an answer, and accept it. It will be helpful to others with this specific problem.